# Let $X,Y: (\Omega, \mathcal F, \mathbb P)\to E$ be independent and $A \in \mathcal F$. Are $X_{\restriction A}, Y_{\restriction A}$ still independent?

Tags: probability-theory

Let $X,Y: (\Omega, \mathcal F, \mathbb P) \to E$ be independent random variables. Let $A \in \mathcal F$ be an event and $\mathcal A := \{F \cap A \mid F \in \mathcal F\}$ the sub-$\sigma$-algebra induced by $A$, ans assume $\mathbb{P}[A]>0$. Let $$\mathbb{P}|_A(\cdot)=\frac{\mathbb{P}(\cdot\cap A)}{\mathbb{P}(A)}$$
Is it true that $X_{\restriction A}, Y_{\restriction A}:(A, \mathcal A, \mathbb P_{\restriction \mathcal A}) \to E$ are still independent?

If $A \in \sigma(X) \cap \sigma(Y)$, then the answerer is clearly yes. Could you elaborate on the general case?

Comment: Please define $X_{|A},Y_{|A}$. Then the question arises if they are ${\cal A}$ measurable.

Comment: @KurtG. $X$ is a map from $\Omega$ to $E$, so we define $X_{\restriction A}$ as the usual [restriction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restriction_(mathematics)) of function.

Comment: I thought so. Let's make our life simple about $E$. Assume this is $\mathbb R$. Hint : $X_{|A}$ and $Y_{|A}$ are inedependent if and only if  $\mathbb P_{|A}(\{X_{|A}>x\}\cap  \{Y_{|A}>y\})=\mathbb P_{|A}(X_{|A}>x)\mathbb P_{|A}(Y_{|A}>y)$ for all $x,y\in\mathbb R$.

Comment: @KurtG. why should $\mathbb{P}_{|A}$ be a probability measure?

Comment: Don't ask me ;).

Comment: @Analyst Is $\mathbb{P}_{\vert A}$ defined the same way, i.e. as the restriction of $\mathbb{P}$ to $\mathcal A$?  If so, that doesn't seem to be a probability measure unless $\mathbb{P}(A)=1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are asking about is equivalent to asking whether $X$ and $Y$ are conditionally independent given $A$. Let $E = \mathbb{R}$ and pick $c \in \mathbb{R}$. Let $A = \{X + Y = c\}$. On $A$ we have $X = c - Y$, so, unless $P(A) = 0$, the restrictions of $X$ and $Y$ to $A$ are not independent.